# Add metadata to apollo graphql response (decoratng the response) with Apollo Server 3

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'd like to return some extra data to my client using ApolloServer 3.

Data is sent back to the client like so:

```
{ data: {
   typeOne
   typeTwo
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to sister this on a per request basis:

```
{
 metadata: {},
 data: {
   typeOne
   typeTwo
  }
}
```

Or even:

```
{ data: {
   typeOne
   typeTwo
   metaData
  }
}
```

But am having trouble getting traction.  One possibility is to place the value on the context and then add it to the response.  That would support the scenario where the metaData key sisters the data key, but I can't find a hook for doing that.

The other would be having a resolver that is always executed, corresponding to the results where the metadata is returned alongside the other types.

I need a push in the right direction!